# Increase Photo-realism in Final render

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, photorealism

I've been working on making some goalkeeper's gloves in blender 2.8 and I feel like I've got the shape and model pretty realistic but just can't the materials, especially the latex of the palm, to look real. I've attached some of my renders below and am hoping someone might have some tips for me. The last photo is the reference I've been using. Thanks for any and all help.

[image: gloves render one]

[image: glove render two]

[image: glove render two]

[image: gloves reference]

Comment: Hello :). For every problem, there is a [BlenderGuru video](https://youtu.be/R1-Ef54uTeU?t=642). 1. Add more geometry, 2. Add surface imperfections, 3. Use HDRI lighting, 4. Post-process your renders

Answer (score 0):

- Use a better lighting, possibly with an HDRI in your scene. A part of the reason why the textures look unreal is that they are completely grey and flat.
- Use image textures and include slight bump mapping for things like the fake leather and so on. What I like to do is get, for example, a leather texture that might be any colour just for the texture, then combine the colour input with a MixRGB node to what I want.